# How to get enumerable or collection of values from WhereSelectListIterator

Tags: c#, linq, reflection, expression

I need to write a generic method for getting distinct values and propertyName is not known in advance. I want to do it using the LINQ expression. I am trying the below way but when getting the result from SelectMethod invoke I am getting WhereSelectListIterator. I want to convert it to IEnumerable so I can call the Distinct method. But I am not to cast it to IEnumerable(as it's not implemented it). How to get Enumerable back from
WhereSelectListIterator or is there any way I can get IEnumerable directly from invoke of generic method.

[image]

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp10
{

```
public class EmployeeEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Employee>
{
    public bool Equals(Employee x, Employee y)
    {
        return x.Id == y.Id;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Employee obj)
    {
        return obj.Id;
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var employees = new List<Employee>()
        { new Employee(){Id=1},
          new Employee(){Id=2},
        new Employee(){Id=1}};

       var values1 =  employees.Select(obj => obj.Id).Distinct();
       var values2 =  employees.Distinct(new EmployeeEqualityComparer());
     var values=   GetDistinctValue(employees, "Id");
    }


    private static readonly MethodInfo DistinctMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods().First(method =>
     method.Name == "Distinct" &&
     method.GetParameters().Length == 1);

    private static readonly MethodInfo SelectMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods().First(method =>
```

method.Name == "Select" &&
method.GetParameters().Length == 2);

```
    public static IEnumerable<object> GetDistinctValue<T>(IEnumerable<T> records, string propertyName)
    {
        try
        {
            ParameterExpression parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
            Expression propertyExpression = Expression.Property(parameterExpression, propertyName);
           var lambda = Expression.Lambda(propertyExpression, parameterExpression);
            var propertyType = propertyExpression.Type;

           // MethodCallExpression compareCall = Expression.Call(typeof(Program), "Compare", Type.EmptyTypes, propertyExpression, Expression.Constant(""), Expression.Constant(""), Expression.Constant(""));


            //LambdaExpression lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(compareCall, parameterExpression);
            MethodInfo genericMethod = SelectMethod.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T),propertyType);

            var result = genericMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { records, lambda.Compile() });
            

            MethodInfo distinctGenericMethod = DistinctMethod.MakeGenericMethod(result.GetType());

            var finalResult = distinctGenericMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { result});


            return null;
        }
        catch(Exception exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
        }
        return null;
    }


}


public class Employee
{
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

}

Comment: Please do not post images of code. Include code and any relevant exception or compiler error as text.

Comment: Post code, i’ll correct mistakes.

Comment: try to cast it like result = result as IEnumerable<object>

Comment: Post only the relevant code. There's a `Distinct` and a `DistinctBy` already. All are already generic, and work by passing *lambdas*. You don't need to know the actual properties when writing the query. You only need to know what `Func<TValue,TKey>` to pass to `DistinctBy`. In `employees.DistinctBy(e=>e.Id)` the lambda `e=>e,Id` is just a parameter. You could pass any method that accepted an `Employee` and returned a single object. While you could construct that method with reflection, you could eliminate the overhead by simply defining that method somewhere

Comment: `But I am not to cast it to IEnumerable` you don't have to. `IEnumerable<T>` is the result of calling an iterator method. Just use the result of your query, either in a `foreach` or with `ToList`, `ToArray` etc. You're overcomplicating things. Even if you really need reflection, the only thing you need is to generate a `Func<Employee,string>` equivalent to `e=>e.Id`. And since the key property of a type is typically known in advance, you can either mark the key property with eg the `Key` attribute instead of passing the name.

Comment: as of now, that result is object type

Answer (score 0):

This is working version of `GetDistinctValue`. Main idea that you can work with `IEnumerable` via `IQueryable` which is dynamic by default.

```cs
public static IEnumerable<object> GetDistinctValue<T>(IEnumerable<T> records, string propertyName)
{
    var parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "e");

    var body = (Expression)Expression.Property(parameterExpression, propertyName);
    if (body.Type != typeof(object))
    {
        body = Expression.Convert(body, typeof(object));
    }

    var lambda = Expression.Lambda(body, parameterExpression);

    // turn IEnumerable into IQueryable
    var queryable = records.AsQueryable();

    var queryExpression = queryable.Expression;

    // records.Select(e => (object)e.propertyName)
    queryExpression = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), nameof(Queryable.Select),
        new[] { typeof(T), typeof(object) }, queryExpression, lambda);

    // records.Select(e => (object)e.propertyName).Distinct()
    queryExpression = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), nameof(Queryable.Distinct), new[] { typeof(object) },
        queryExpression);

    // creating IQueryable<object> from generated expression
    var resultQuery = queryable.Provider.CreateQuery<object>(queryExpression);

    // turn IQueryable into IEnumerable
    return resultQuery.AsEnumerable();
}
```